# Is it possible to import class which lies in project folder?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following setup of a Scala application :

```
 -> /ApplicationA
  -> /project
  - > /build.sbt

 -> /ApplicationB
  -> /project
  -> /build.sbt

 -> /Common
  -> /project
   ->CommonCommand.scala
  -> /build.sbt
```

Both ApplicationA and ApplicationB have dependency on Common and in both build.sbt files I have a custom task which should send some parameters to a method in CommonCommand class, but I can't import it or do anything like that. Are there any options to do this, or I should duplicate CommonCommand.scala in project folder in ApplicationA and ApplicationB ?

Comment: How are you building your projects? If you are building and producing one artefact per project, then you should be able to import the needed dependencies of Common project into ApplicationA and ApplicationB

Comment: I'm  receiving ApplicationA and ApplicationB artifacts by running
 *sbt stage* command. In theirs build.sbt files I have `lazy val common=ProjectRef(file(..."), "common") ` 
and `lazy val application= (project in file(".")).dependsOn(common) `
  Also I have `lazy val commonCommand= taskKey[Unit]` and this task just calls the method of *CommonCommand.scala*

Comment: So, if this *CommonCommand* class is not duplicated in project folder of ApplicationA and ApplicationB I can't access them from theirs build.sbt

Comment: @tcafrin22, first of all it is not clear whether you want to call `CommonCommand` as a part of ApplicationA itself or as a part of ApplicationA **_build process_** (i.e. frm sbt build of ApplicationA). Could you clarify your requirements?

Comment: @SergGr I think it should be a part of  **build process** . But as it's for now, I just  created this `lazy val commonCommand= taskKey[Unit]` and run it before compile. This command  calls
 **CommonCommand**
  from itself  `commonCommand:={ CommonCommand.exampleMethod(...)}`.  
And this 
*exampleMethod*
 takes as the argument some Sequence of predefined Strings. That's why I'm not passing it through the console.